# How do I lower case the response discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So basicly the person is trying to guess whats the name of the anime! What I want it to do is to ingore the case sentativity! How can I do that? Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    def check(m):
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
    Question1 = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/dc/DARLING_in_the_FRANXX%2C_second_key_visual.jpg/220px-DARLING_in_the_FRANXX%2C_second_key_visual.jpg'
    Question2 = 'http://www.j1studios.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/Trinity-Seven-Header-001-20160707.jpg'
    Question3 = 'https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/hotlink/images/encyc/A18170-2511174083.1466822675.jpg'
    Question4 = 'https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/hotlink/images/encyc/A16344-911899268.1425205899.jpg'
    Question5 = 'https://www.theanimedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/20061004422210.jpg'
    Question6 = 'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.zvtbvP4JZNrrlAKPnclMpwHaEK?pid=Api&rs=1&adlt=strict'
    Question7 = 'https://mangathrill.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/pjimage-1-4.jpg'
    Question8 = 'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.xV_2srfdOhEre9Vua-u6zAHaFb?pid=Api&rs=1&adlt=strict'
    Question9 = 'https://img1.looper.com/img/gallery/the-untold-truth-of-hunter-x-hunter/intro-1591800144.jpg'
    Question10 = 'https://i1.wp.com/static.anidub.com/blog/2014/09/Seirei-Tsukai-no-Blade-Dance.jpg'
    questionlist = [Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8, Question9, Question10]
    question = random.choice(questionlist)
    await ctx.send("What is the title name of this anime?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(question)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await msg.lower()
    if question == Question1:
        if msg.content == "darling in the franxx":
            earnings = random.randrange(300, 500)
            await ctx.send(f"You did good! You got an earning of **{earnings}** coins!")
        else:
            earnings = random.randrange(0, 200)
            await ctx.send(f"Did you even try? You got **{earnings}** coins!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)` returns you the `discord.Message` class. And `discord.Message` has no attribute `lower()`. But it has `content`, `content` returns the **string value** of the message.

And also `await msg.lower()` is a weird usage, it's not a coroutine so you can't `await` it.

So you can simply do:

```py
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
msg_content = msg.content.lower()
if question == Question1:
        if msg_content == "darling in the franxx":
            earnings = random.randrange(300, 500)
            await ctx.send(f"You did good! You got an earning of **{earnings}** coins!")
        else:
            earnings = random.randrange(0, 200)
            await ctx.send(f"Did you even try? You got **{earnings}** coins!")
```

And also, I suggest you to put questions and question list out of the command, it becomes more optimized.